# zend framework 2 project in server doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, server

Working with zf2, we have configured the project successfully in local env, we deployed the same code to server, but there..only the `IndexController` action is working.
like `www.project.com/public/` works,

but when I access other modules like

```
www.project.com/public/country doesn't work.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means the mod_rewrite rules to rewrite all requests to your index.php file are not being used. Generally this means either:

- The `.htaccess` file was not uploaded (check the public folder on the server to see if it's there)
- The `.htaccess` file is being ignored (check `AllowOverride` for the vhost on the live server)

Also, really `public/` should not appear in your URLs. Unless you are using shared hosting (where this can be tricky), you want to point your vhost's document root at the public folder.

Comment: .htaccess was uploaded & we will be removing this public/ later, but as of now we kept it & checking the things..can u pls help me regd "check AllowOverride for the vhost on the live server"

Comment: Your Apache Virtual Host should look something like the example in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server . The `AllowOverride All` line on there is what tells Apache to check each folder for .htaccess files. Check the virtual host on your server to see whether this is present. Note that this is not a ZF-specific issue, you would have the same issue with any PHP framework that uses URL rewriting.

Comment: we haven't create any virutal host for this, even in the localhost also we are just working without the virual host, it works there...so in the same way we have in the server..won't this work out?

Comment: If you didn't create a vhost there may already be one, otherwise, it'll be the default Apache configuration. Either way the Apache config is where you need to look.

Comment: can u pls help me, how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

In a proper Zend setup an error should come from Zend. When you get an error like this, returned from Apache, your apache configuration is not working. Your Zend application isn't even considered, i.e. the index.php in your public folder.

It's a save guess that your `[public/].htaccess` isn't used. Check your apache web configuration. Most likely you're missing the `AllowOverride All` statement which is usually inside the `<Directory>` statement.

And as mentioned by Tim you really should not have `public/` in your path to begin with.